# How does useRef() cause a view change without a re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

So, I have this basic code below.

In the code when the user clicks on the button, it focuses on the input field and types in the word "test".

How does this happen since the state is never changed? i.e since a "re-render" is not occurring- how does the view change?

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
    inputRef.current.value = "test";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef}></input>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!!</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: The input is uncontrolled since you do not provide any `value` prop and the focus state is generally not managed by react at all. So there is no re-render needed. The input element in the actual DOM tracks those states itself. Your component doesn't know or set them.

Comment: That is a reference to the element itself. So, it is handled by the browser as an input element not by React. The changes done to the input element is stored in the reference object. You can `console.log(inputRef.current)` which shows the actual DOM element properties along with React properties.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
as mentioned above uncontrolled form elements are a way to go around the render lifecycle. In a controlled `<input />` you'd use `value` and `onChange`. in an uncontrolled `<input />` you'd use `defaultValue` and `ref`. When choosing the uncontrolled approach you're basically saying: "I don't need to respond to changes, I will fetch the value imperatively when I need it via `ref.current.value`".

Comment: On a side note, if you're dabbling into forms, you might benefit from checking out a ready-made form package such as https://react-hook-form.com. Managing form state is harder than it initially looks.